# rails g activeadmin_addons:install " is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have already posted this issue on github. I haven't received any reply yet. Please anyone is familiar with this issue, help me fix this.
I added

```
gem 'activeadmin_addons'
```

to gen file and ran bundle install. I am using Active Admin 1.0.0.pre4. Rails 4.2.6 and ruby 2.2.4.
Once the bundle installation is done. I ran

```
rails g activeadmin_addons:install
```

as told on the gem documentation. But it is returning the following:

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 19666
    Could not find generator 'activeadmin_addons:install'. Maybe you meant 'active_admin:install', 'active_admin:assets' or 'active_admin:devise'
    Run `rails generate --help` for more options.
```

Comment: have you restarted spring before running `activeadmin_addons:install` ?

Comment: I did `spring stop` and did `rails g activeadmin_addons:install` still the same error.